# how to call anther method in java with asm

Tags: java-bytecode-asm

Newer to asm.
I need to modify behavior of a method in an unmodifiable jar.
Codes like below:

```
class A {
    D callA() {
        if (XXX) {
            // XXX
            return callB();
        } else {
            return callC();
        }
    }
    D callB() {
        // XXX
    }
    D callC() {
        // XXX
    }
}
A a = new A();
D d = a.callA();
```

Here, I want the result of `a.callA()`, return the result of `a.callB()`.
And I konw asm may be a way to solve this.
How can I make this?
Any help will be appreciated, thank you!